# How do I hide edit this list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

[image]

I would like to know how i hide edit this list and only leave new item.

Answer (score 6):

Follow below Steps:

- Go to **List Settings**
- Click on **Advanced Settings** link under General Settings.
- In Quick Edit select “No” in ‘Allow items in this list to be edited using Quick Edit?’
  [image]
- Save the settings.

**Reference:** http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/15/sharepoint-2013-disable-quick-editing-in-lists/

Comment: How do I hide the entries I have hiden edit item . thanks for your help :)

Comment: Kindly ask new question as another question or if it is related to your current question then add it in your question.

Comment: Kindly mark answer as accepted, if it's helpful to you! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the entries by modifying the view from the ribbon and under filter section and check the Show items only when the following is true checkbox

```
set filter as "ID" is equal to "0"
```

which will result in "There are no items to show in this view of the "List Name" list." for the view.